# Как передать данные в textBox с другого класса C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, многопоточность

Есть форма Main с классом Main.cs, есть класс Threads.cs и есть Parser.cs.

По кнопке в Main запускаю потоки в классе Threads.cs из класса Threads.cs запускаю Parser.cs. Пишу результат оработки класса Parser.cs в класс с глобальными переменными и вывожу таймером в textBox, но возникают ошибки, потому что foreach не успевает перезаписывать масив из за работы потоков. Как можно результат выполнения класса Parser.cs писать сразу в textBox в Main.cs?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всю работу с GUI должен выполнять главный поток программы (Main.cs).

Строку текста нужно передавать из Parser.cs в Main.cs через глобальную переменную.

Поскольку строка - это массив символов, то после её передачи Parser.cs должен установить флаг окончания передачи - глобальную переменную типа boolean.

Main.cs должен периодически (например по таймеру) проверять состояние этого флага, и выводить текст в textBox, только когда строка полностью передана из Parser.cs.

Comment: У меня из каждого потока выхдит по 10 строк, я запускаю много потоков, но таймер с обновлением не справляется, потому что потоки постоянно ее обновляют. Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Типовым решением является ведение лога.

Comment: Можно точнее про лог?

Comment: Вести лог - это в файл записывать сообщения о событиях.

Comment: А как мне это поможет? Мне вести лог а потом просто считовать по таймеру?

Comment: Если программа работает слишком быстро, то нет смысла искать какие-то способы её затормозить, чтобы пользователь мог внимательно ознакомиться, что там происходит в процессе работы. Достаточно вести лог сессии, а в конце сообщать, что всё ОК, или что были такие-то ошибки.